# Save a textarea into a file using lua

Tags: post, lua, textarea

i have a webserver (uhttpd) that uses CGI with LUA.
I made a form with a textarea.
What i need is saving the content of the textarea on a file located in /etc/list.txt
I think that the LUA script have to read the POST variables, and then save them into a local file /etc/list.txt.

I already have the script for reading the file:

```
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end

function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines(file) do 
    lines[#lines + 1] = line
  end
  return lines
end

local file = '/etc/list.txt'
local lines = lines_from(file)

print ('<textarea name="mensaje" cols="40" rows="40">')

for k,v in pairs(lines) do
  print(v)
end

print ("</textarea>")
```

This script shows me the content of file.txt onto the textarea.
Now i need a button "Save" that POST the textarea again into the file.

Thank you for your help and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Small critique: `lines_from` files is overwriting a global variable `lines` every time it is called. That should be made local. Also opening and closing the file to see if it exists before reading it is wasteful. That operation can be folded into `lines_from`:

```
function lines_from(filename)
  local lines = {}
  local file = io.open(filename)
  if file then 
      for line in file:lines(file) do 
        lines[#lines + 1] = line
      end
      file:close();
  end
  return lines
end
```

In your case there's no reason to even read the text as lines. Just read all the file's text:

```
function text_from(filename)
  local text = ''
  local file = io.open(filename)
  if file then 
      text = file:read('*a') 
      file:close();
  end
  return text
end

local file = 'test.lua'
local text = text_from(file)

print ('<textarea name="mensaje" cols="40" rows="40">')
print(text)
print ("</textarea>")
```

To write the text back to the file, just reverse the procedure, opening the file in "w+" mode (replace existing data):

```
function save_text_to(filename, text)
  local file = io.open(filename, 'w+')
  if file then 
      text = file:write(text);
      file:close();
  end
end

save_text_to('foo', text)
```